# Cocoa: Auto-Install .pkg

Tags: cocoa, authentication

I have a Cocoa application that, periodically, needs to install pkg X onto the system.  I know that I need to work with the Authentication Services framework to get this going, and I'm reviewing it right now as I've never worked with it before.

However, pkg X updates frequently and I don't want to prompt my users for a password every time my application needs to install it.  Is there a way such that I can grant my application a "certificate" of sorts such that, if a user enables a checkbox when prompted for credentials one time, they will never have to re-enter them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at Apple's [SMJobBless](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.  Using the technique illustrated there, you can created a privileged helper tool.  You would need authentication/authorization once to bless the tool and not again after that.  The tool could use `/usr/sbin/installer` to install the package.